# prevent a checkbox menu from animating on page load

Tags: css

I have a hamburger menu that functions with a checkbox to animate a menu up and down the page. when the page loads, the menu will slide down and back up the page. What I'd like it to do is just stay hidden when the page loads. Here's the CSS of how it's set up now:

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: var(--taupe-color);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu .toggler:checked~.overlay {
  animation: slideDown 2s forwards;
}

.menu .toggler:not(:checked)~.overlay {
  animation: slideUp 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%)
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0%)
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%)
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

I've tried setting the opacity to 0 in the overlay class and then setting it to 1 in the animation which fixes the loading problem but when the checkbox is not checked, it no longer animates back up the page, it will just disappear. Using display none also doesn't solve the problem. Is there a way for the menu to stay hidden during page loading and only animate when the user interacts with the menu button/checkbox?

EDIT: adding HTML

```
        <div class="menu">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
        
        <div class="icon">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="overlay">
            <nav>
                <div id="nav-links"></div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: HTML, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out a solution. Essentially, instead of preventing the keyframe from animating on page load, I made it hidden so you couldn't see it. I chose to do this by setting the initial opacity to 0.

```
.overlay {
position: fixed;
background: var(--taupe-color);
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
visibility: hidden;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
}
```

Now the only issue is to set the opacity back to 1 before animating it. I realized that I could set opacity back to 1 during the hover state. You'll need to do this to the menu button when it's checked and unchecked:

```
.menu .toggler:checked:hover ~ .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}

.menu .toggler:not(:checked):hover ~ .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}
```

this allowed the menu animation to be hidden during page load and only be visible once the user hovers over the mouse button and clicks it.

EDIT:
I realized that the menu disappears once the user navigates away form the menu button so I needed to find a way for the menu to remain visible even when the user is no longer hovering over the menu button. I think there's a way to keep the hover state even after the mouse moves using js but since my menu is full screen, I figured I can create a hover state for the menu screen itself. so far I haven't found any bugs. I just added this code to my previous solution:

```
.overlay:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Edit 2:
Ok the previous solution didn't really work well because if the mouse was not over the menu while it was closing it would abruptly disappear. Also, it did not account for users on touch screens. The best solution was to create an onclick

```
onclick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.opacity='1'"
```

so long story short, I could not find a way to prevent a keyframe animation from happening on page load but I could hide it and then bring it back. going to mark myself as the answer now

Comment: so actually this doesn't fully solve the problem. because menu disappears when the user moves mouse away from the checkbox and no longer hovers. trying to think if there's a way to hover + checked as a way to keep opacity at 1